# I am not able to load another html page which I have created as student.html after javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, vs-web-site-project

Please tell me which function I can use to open student.html when the username and password is matching with the value I described in scrip tag.

```
<form>
    <input
        name="username"
        type="text"
        id="txt_username"
        class="text1"
        ondrop="return false;" 
        onpaste="return false;"
        style="color:#0000C0;border-style:Solid;font-family:verdana;font-size:Small;"
    />
    <input
        name="password"
        type="password"
        id="txt_password"
        class="text1"
        style="color:#0000C0;background-color:White;;border-style:Solid;font-family:verdana;font-size:Small;"
    />  
    <input
        type="submit"
        value="Login"
        onclick="validate()"
    />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById("txt_username");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("txt_password");
    if (text1.value == "root" && text2.value == "root") {
        alert("ok")
        load("student.html");
    } else {
        alert("fail");
        load("error.html");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Change window.location to any address you need

Comment: You should most definitely not verify username and password in frontend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 window.location.assign
```

---

---

```js
function validate() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById("txt_username");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("txt_password");
    if (text1.value == "root" && text2.value == "root") {
        window.location.assign("student.html");        
    } else {
        window.location.assign("error.html");                
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input
        name="username"
        type="text"
        id="txt_username"
        class="text1"
        ondrop="return false;" 
        onpaste="return false;"
        style="color:#0000C0;border-style:Solid;font-family:verdana;font-size:Small;"
    />
    <input
        name="password"
        type="password"
        id="txt_password"
        class="text1"
        style="color:#0000C0;background-color:White;;border-style:Solid;font-family:verdana;font-size:Small;"
    />  
    <input
        type="submit"
        value="Login"
        onclick="validate()"
    />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why this is not working in my system?? After entering the username and password it is not loading any page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.replace("student.html")` to replace the current document. Or you can use `window.location.href = "student.html";`.

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate(event)">
    <input
        name="username"
        type="text"
        id="txt_username"
        class="text1"
        ondrop="return false;" 
        onpaste="return false;"
        style="color:#0000C0;border-style:Solid;font-family:verdana;font-size:Small;"
    />
    <input
        name="password"
        type="password"
        id="txt_password"
        class="text1"
        style="color:#0000C0;background-color:White;;border-style:Solid;font-family:verdana;font-size:Small;"
    />  
    <input
        type="submit"
        value="Login"
    />
</form>
<script>
function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text1 = document.getElementById("txt_username");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("txt_password");
    if (text1.value == "root" && text2.value == "root") {
        window.location.replace("student.html");        
    } else {
        window.location.replace("error.html");                
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: change your button type from "submit" to "button".

Comment: Or you can remove onclick event from Login button and register onsubmit event for the form. @amu check the code snippet of my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My code is working fine now:)